# React Icon Click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inheritance, icons

I'm using npm react-icons on some buttons.

Unfortunately, the icon stops the onClick attribute from working. If you click the button in the corner, outside the icon, it works fine.

I was wondering if there is a simple solution that does not involve passing down the onClick function as a prop and going into the react-icons code and adding the onClick to it.

the code in the module is

```
    import React from 'react'
    import Icon from 'react-icon-base'

    const FaArrowUp = props => (
        <Icon viewBox="0 0 40 40" {...props}>
            <g><path d="m37.5 21.7q0 1.1-0.9 2l-1.6 1.7q-0.9 0.8-2.1 0.8-1.2 0-2-0.8l-6.5-6.6v15.7q0 1.2-0.9 1.9t-2 0.7h-2.9q-1.1 0-2-0.7t-0.8-1.9v-15.7l-6.6 6.6q-0.8 0.8-2 0.8t-2-0.8l-1.7-1.7q-0.8-0.9-0.8-2 0-1.2 0.8-2.1l14.6-14.5q0.7-0.8 2-0.8 1.2 0 2 0.8l14.5 14.5q0.9 0.9 0.9 2.1z"/></g>
        </Icon>
    )

    export default FaArrowUp
```

my render method where I import the icon has

```
 <button name='up' onClick={this.move}> <FaArrowUp /> </button>
```

Comment: I've tried wrapping the icon component in span and div, giving the span and the div the `name` and `onClick` attributes, and neither one worked.

Comment: Your code should work! Maybe, you should try wrapping it in a anchor tag -
 `<a>`

Comment: <a> tag doesn't work either. The icon turns red on hover even, but the onClick function will not fire...

Comment: are u using IE? - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4963

Comment: I am not using IE

Comment: Can you post the code for `this.move`? You would get this behavior if you are using `stopPropagation`.

Comment: Imagine that this.move points to a method that only console.logs "onClick fired", since that is basically all I need to happen

Answer (score 2):

After check package on github i guess you should try this:

```
 <button name='up' onClick={this.move}> <FaArrowUp onClick={() => this.move}> /> </button>
```

Comment: Didn't work. :( I tried adding the name attribute to it as well, and both wrapped in anonymous function and not wrapped. Neither one worked.

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this, I used font-awesome icons

```
<div onClick={() =>{setShowPassword('text')}}>
            <i class="fa fa-eye" id="togglePassword" style={eyeIcon}></i>
   </div>
```

**Note**: In your **onClick** you can add your desired function.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I also ended up here having the same issue. Not really sure why, but the icons didn't like being inside a div that was set to relative.

Removing the `position: relative` from the parent div fixed it for me.

I really needed it though, so I wrapped them both in another div and set that to relative. Interestingly, it didn't mind that as much. Strange but hopefully this helps someone.

Will potentially update this answer with any more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using data attributes in your click handler (e.g. `e.currentTarget.dataset.something`) use `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target`.

`event.target` is the most deeply nested element that caused the event.

`event.currentTarget` is the element that listens to the event (where the event listener is attached to).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using click handler (e.g. event.target.name) use event.currentTarget instead of event.target.